# What is the correct language for JSON

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error

I have a JSON file called `myjson.cfg` that looks like this:

```
{    
        "values": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3,
            "d": 4
        },
    "sales": [
        { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": "karl" },
        { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": "karl" }
    ]
}
```

and in my html I include the file like this: 
`<script type='text/javascript' src="myjson.cfg' "></script>`

However, I am getting a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

error in line two which is this one

`"values": {`

Why ? When I look at the [example](http://json.org/example.html) it looks pretty similar to me?!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: For starters, that example you pasted in is missing the closing } and you're not assigning the json object to any variable, so you won't even be able to use it later in the page.

Comment: That was my mistake, the file is longer, I updated the file

Comment: The example is an object called `glossary`. Yours is not an object, it's two objects combined into an unnamed object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON isn't Javascript. You can't load a JSON file in a script tag. You need to use AJAX to load JSON from the web. The JSON file should be served with an `application/json` content-type.

I suggest you investigate XMLHttpRequest, or, if you want an easier ride, jQuery's AJAX methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing bracket "}"

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "values": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4
    }
}
```

A useful tool for situations like this is a JSON validator.
I ran your snippit through [this one](http://jsonlint.com/) and it pointed the error out.

EDIT:
Now that you have updated your question, your JSON is valid. But don't hesitate to reach for a JSON validator when you have errors like this.

Another good one that you can download locally is [json-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-lint)

Comment: Hi thanks, that was my mistake the file is longer I updated it and ran it using your validator, it is valid

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
{  
    "values":
             {
               "a": 1,
               "b": 2,
               "c": 3,
               "d": 4
              }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gxrnq79/1/